# как изменить ширину столбца в datatables

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, datatable

как изменить ширину столбца в datatables? Он как-то автоматически подгоняется, а мне нужно задать ему фиксированную ширину. Пробовал уже всё: и через атрибут `width`, и через инлайн стили и через `!important`. Я думаю, это нужно сделать как-то через js.

```
$("#table").DataTable({});

<table width="100%" id="table" bordercolor="#E7E7E7" border="2" align="center">
  <thead class="first-row">
    <td class="table-first" width="50px" align="center" data-orderable="false">
      <input type="checkbox" id="main-chb" class="fst-chbox">
    </td>
    <td class="table-cenetr" align="center" data-orderable="false"><span class="table-captions table-photos">Фото</span></td>
    <td class="table-cenetr table-art" align="center"><span class="table-captions">Артикул</span></td>
    <td class="table-cenetr" align="center"><span class="table-captions">Товар</span></td>
    <td class="table-cenetr table-price" align="center"><span class="table-captions">Цена</span></td>
    <td class="table-cenetr table-status" align="center"><span class="table-captions">Статус</span></td>
    <td class="table-end" align="center" data-orderable="false"></td>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td class="table-first" width="50px" align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="oth-check"></td>
    <td class="table-cenetr table-photo" align="center"><i class="icon-eye"></i></p>
    </td>
    <td class="table-cenetr table-art" align="center">
      <p>АБВГДЕЁ1234536789</p>
    </td>
    <td class="table-cenetr">
      <p>Товар №1</p>
    </td>
    <td class="table-cenetr table-price" align="center"><span>5 200.00</span></td>
    <td class="table-cenetr table-status" align="center"><span>Вкл<i class="icon-down btn-down"></i></span></td>
    <td class="table-end" align="center">
      <input type="checkbox" id="cog-ChBox-1" onchange="chb1Fun()" class="cog-chbox">
      <label for="cog-ChBox-1" class="chbox-cog">
                                        <i class="icon-cog"></i>
                                    </label>
      <div class="cog-menu cog-menu1">
        <ul class="cog-list">
          <li>Настройка 1</li>
          <li>Настройка 2</li>
          <li>Настройка 3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

как сделать первый столбец с чекбоксом шириной в 50px?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте стилями и все будет нормально

```
    #table td:first-child {
        width: 50px!important;
    }
```

Вот только вчера делал

```
    #table td {
        text-align: center;
        width: 10%!important;
    }
    #table td:first-child {
        width: 5%!important;
    }
    #table td:nth-child(2) {
        text-align: left;
        width: 45%!important;
    }
```

И все отлично:

- у всех ячеек выравнивание по-центру, кроме второй;
- у всех ячеек ширина 10%, кроме 1ой и 2ой (у первой 5%, у второй 45%)

Comment: не работает. я пробовал

Comment: Дополнил ответ, только вчера это делал. Проверяйте стили, значить что-то у вас перебивает

Comment: А возможно, чтобы ширина была в пикселях, но при изменении экрана она оставалась такой же?

Comment: Ну если вы её зададите в пикселях, то она однозначно останется без изменений

Comment: в том то и дело, что нет)

Comment: дайте ссылку сайт

Comment: Первый столбец меняет свою ширину, когда контенту уже некуда деться https://jsfiddle.net/z8rntw1m/9/ а так он постоянно 50px